# Install an application offline

Tags: networking

I have a server not connected to the internet. I need to install snmp-d. How can i do this without sudo apt-get install snmpd?

The .deb file for this is too small to be the program.

Comment: "The .deb file for this is too small to be the program."  sorry how so?

Answer (score 0):

- size of snmp package is 154 kB
- installed version is 550 kB

Installing for an off line system can be done with several methods:

1. You can start at the [Ubuntu packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/snmp) site.

   - Search for the package name in the Ubuntu version you need.
   - Download all the DEBs that state "depends" unless you can determine your system already has that version Do the same for all the DEBs that are inside the link to that package.
   - Decide if you need the "recommends" packages and if so download them too. Including all the DEBs in the link of that DEB.
2. From a running system that is the same version (ie. both are 17.10):

   - If you have a running system you can have that system download all the packages. By downloading snmp it will also download all the needed dependencies. The DEBs will be in /var/cache/archives/ and can be copied to another system. Mind though this assumes the systems are similar; otherwise you might end up download just some of the required packages that the other system wants. You can always use method 1 to download missing packages.

---

Installing without `apt` is done with `dpkg -i {debian install file}` in the order of lowest dependency first. You can not install snmp without having the correct libc6 so libc6 would go 1st (if you need libc6 that is).